# How to upload python packages not listed on Google Cloud Assured Open source software artifact repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I have been reading through Google cloud Assured Open source software documentation and came across list of supported python packages hosted on their repository - https://cloud.google.com/assured-open-source-software/docs/supported-packages#python

Having read its documentation, most of it talks about setting up direct, remote or virtual repository to  **download** the packages. There is no mention anywhere in the documentation for a use case if we want to **upload** packages that are not in the supported list of packages (https://cloud.google.com/assured-open-source-software/docs/supported-packages#python) . Asking this because I want to leverage the benefits of Assured Open source software like vulnerability scanning in particular.

There's is any clear cut mention of uploading feature, hence, is it assumed that this service is **download **only?

Comment: That's the way the service works! You can't upload your own open source library to assured workload. The proposed library is a list of curated one by Google. I don't know the exact process. Yes there automatic things, but maybe more. In any case it's only at the Google initiative. You could ask the support to perform a request to the team, but I'm not sure how it works...

Comment: Also, Google repositories support vulnerability scanning. You tagged Artifact registry which supports canning.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - thanks for your response and its noted. with just download only certain packages doesn't completely remove the developer TOIL hence why I was curious to know why it is the way it is. Anyways, thanks for now, I my solution is remote repository to Assured OSS as priority 1 and priority 2 will be my local hosted pypiserver python repo.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for your response, Yes I am aware of artifact registry support scanning and on same note I was keen to explore package pre-scanning before storing images to artifact registry - i mean what is the point once in providing scanning post all build is complete!, wish we could do prior and only submit build low severity vulnerabilities

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere, Based on this documentation, https://cloud.google.com/assured-open-source-software/docs/download-python-packages#access_packages_not_available_in                                            
if the packages are not in Cloud AOSS, the python packages can be accessed https://us-python.pkg.dev/cloud-aoss/python/simple , however this link is broken

Comment: I got the information from the PM of the feature. Send an email to customer-support-aoss@google.com to let them know the (name, version, language) of the libraries that you expect. They will be able to add them to the backlog and prioritize their integration in assured OSS.

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere for the information. I got same information from our partner engineer and have already send them the list.